# How to change name row using expresssion in SSRS report?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-tablix, tableau-api

I had generated a report .In one of columns i need to change the names of rows in that column.
In first row
clumnA    clumnB

Value     78

grade     85

But i need to change in report to get output like.I need to rename value and grade

clumnA  clumnb

Number    78

Percent   78

Note i dont want make any changes in Stored Proc

Note:To get value i am using expression below

```
=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(Fields!Rating.Value = 3, Fields!Measurement.Value, Nothing)
```

My Answer is

```
  =Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(Fields!Rating.Value = 3, "Number", Nothing)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this sort of thing with the `SWITCH` function:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Rating.Value = 3, "Number", Fields!Rating.Value = 4, "Percent", True, Fields!ColumnA.Value)
```

Note that I am using `True` at the end of the SWITCH function to simulate `Else` - that is, if none of the previous conditions hold, the value for `True` will be returned, so we get whatever is in `ColumnA` except when `Rating` is 3 or 4.